# "Application must run" requirement for Ruby assignment, create gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

EDIT: In short, what do I need to do to create a running application in Ruby, do I need to create a gem?

ORIGINAL QUESTION THAT SUCKED:

I've never taken any programming classes, or had assignments before so I'm asking this question in hopes this is clear to someone who has had many programming assignments before.

Basically the instructions state, "The Application must Run."

The instructions on the assignment uploader state that no executable files should be uploaded and the application should be put into a .zip.

For a second I thought I'd just create the app code locally, zip all the files, and upload them,  but now I'm second guessing that. It seems like I should create a gem out of my application and then the readme that would be uploaded would instruct them to just install the gem?

Am I on the right track here? I suppose my question can be stated as, I need to create a ruby application that will run, is the best way to do that by creating a gem? Or am I completely over thinking this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think for a beginner, creating a whole gem is too much to ask. But ask your instructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely thing is that it means this:

> The application must run via executing the command `ruby myapp.rb`

So it "must run" when you pass the filename of you code to the `ruby` executable.

Anything else wouldn't make much sense. If you are required to make a gem, that would likely have been explicitly clear. But you should clarify this with your instructor, as there isn't a lot to go on here.